# Image straightening algorithm

Tags: c#, php, image-processing, opencv, imagemagick

I am looking for a way to auto-straighten my images, and I was wondering if anyone has come across any algorithms to do this.  I realize that the ability to do this depends on the content of the image, but any known algorithms would be a start.

I am looking to eventually implement this in `C#` or `PHP`, however, I am mainly after the algorithm right now.

Is this possible with `OpenCV`? `ImageMagick`? Others?

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: Perhaps an example of what you mean by "auto-straighten" would be nice ...

Comment: What do you mean by straightening?  Alignment of horizon?  Compensation for optical distortions of the lens (pincushion, barrel)?  If possible, post a sample image along with your explanation.

Comment: Alignment of horizon is the best description. But I know this is case-by-case so I was just hoping for some information pertaining to ANY form of image straightening/alignment.

Comment: I think in its present form the question is too broad. Perhaps if you post some examples on your intended usage ...

Comment: it is generally impossible to align *any* image.  Objective alignment is always relative to something -- e.g. the horizon, or a building directly overhead (it will be vertical and not subject to perspective effect).  Aircraft in flight, objects in space and anything that generally doesn't have a reference can't be aligned objectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my idea:

1. edge detection (Sobel, Prewitt, Canny, ...)
2. hough transformation (horizontal lines +/- 10 degrees)
3. straighten the image according to the longest/strongest line

This is obviously not going to work in any type of image. This is just meant to fuel the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Most OCR programs straighten the scanned image prior to running recognition. You probably find good code in the many open source'd OCR programs, such Tesseract

Answer (score 0):

Of course this does depend on what type of images you want to straighten, but there seems to be some resources available for automatic straightening of text scans.

[One post](http://objectmix.com/graphics/144337-automated-straightening-skewed-text-scans-2.html#post501230) I found mentioned 3 programs that could do auto-straightening:

- TechSoft's PixEdit 7.0.11
- Mystik Media's AutoImager 3.03
- Spicer's Imagenation 7.50

If manual straightening is acceptable, there are many tutorials out there for how to straighten them manually using Photoshop; just google "image straightening"

Comment: Dead link after a decade!

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick has the -deskew option. This will simply rotate the image to be straight.

Most commercial OCR engines like ABBYY FineReader and Nuance OmniPage do this automatically.

The Leptonica research library has a command line tool called skewtest which will rotate the image.

I have not found a library which can take an image which has been distorted in any other way (like pin cushion or if it has been moved during a scanning operation, or removing the warp at the edge of a book). I am looking for a library or tool that can do this, but cannot find one.

Patrick.